# How to keep css animation effect?

Tags: css

I have some slide animation in css. There is any chance to keep this effect?

```
#arch{
    margin-top:5%;
    width:222px;
    height:222px;
    background-image:url(img/arch.jpg);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000000;

    }

#arch:hover{
        -webkit-animation:przesuniecie 1s 1 alternate;
        }

@-webkit-keyframes przesuniecie
{
from {width:222px;}
to {width:0px;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean to have to the element slide away on hover, and slide out when the mouse leaves?  I suggest putting the :hover on the parent element:

```
*:hover > #arch{
    -webkit-animation:przesuniecie 1s 1 alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes przesuniecie
{
    from {width:222px;}
    to {width:0px;}
}
```

Depending on what the parent element is, you may need to wrap the #arch element in a `<div>`.

Also, you may need to use CSS transitions instead of CSS animations, so that the animation doesn't abruptly end on mouseout:

```
#arch{
    -webkit-transition:width 1s;
    width: 220px;
}

*:hover > #arch{
    width: 0;
}
```

(Don't forget to include the other variations of the property for the other browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `:hover` event and let it sit.

Comment: yea but I want that animat goeas after I point at div.
BTW. removeing hover will not help all in all it still back to 222px aftre animation.

Comment: @Dudi im confused, you want to keep the animation but keep the `:hover` event as well? What exactly are you looking to keep?

Comment: @Ander Ilich I want to slide tile, and read a text, which is under that tile.

Comment: @Dudi (still trying to understand, bear with me for a sec) What does the tile have to do with the effect you want to keep? And what exactly does the effect do to the tile that you want to keep it? Can you provide a demo so we can understand clearer?

Comment: @Anders Wait for it... I'm looking for it

Comment: @Anders OK [here](http://www.gpsbhp.pl/category/oferta/) but I want that black rectangle have same size as whole white rectangle, and when I hover it, black rectangle goes to left and now I can see white rectangle. I hope that will help.

Comment: @Dudi So im looking at your demo right now, so you're saying that there is content that is supposed to appear when we hover the elements in your page correct? As i hover, the boxes go white and the background fades a bit, i don't see any other content.

Comment: @Anders yea  Brilliand to hit the nail on the head. :)